# Скомпилировать apk со всеми .so + proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, ndk

На Android Studio 3.2 компилирую apk на устройство без прогуарда и в apk добавляются все либы .so.Как включаю прогуард получаю apk только с одной либой под архитектуру устройства на котором компилирую

```
    splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        include 'x86','x86_64','armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Как заставить Android Studio 3.2 с включенным прогуардом создавать apk со всеми либами?

Comment: При чём тут Proguard? Это обфускатор java-кода, на компиляцию натива и сборку APK он никак не влияет. AGP по умолчанию включает в APK либы всех поддерживаемых архитектур. Такой блок `splits` указывает сборщику произвести отдельный APK для каждой архитектуры и ещё один со всеми разом (в его имени будет суффикс `universal`

Comment: При том что без прогуарда работает

Comment: Мне вам поверить на слово или покажете свои настройки? Гадать на кофейной гуще здесь никто не будет - либо показываете достаточно информации для того чтобы понять что вы делаете, либо разбирайтесь сами.

Comment: Показал файл gradle отвечающий за сборку апк.Или вам надо было скинуть весь коммерческий проект целиком?,впрочем вопрос уже решен, а для собирателей кода нет желания выкладывать.

Comment: Почитайте справку: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Мне нафиг не нужен ваш проект, но по информации, которой вы нас удостоили невозможно дать ответ. Откуда мне знать что вы такое делаете с прогуардом, что аж натив не собирается или не пакуется. Впрочем дело ваше, вы сами сюда пришли за решением проблемы - сами и решайте насколько вы в этом заинтересованы.

Comment: Да проблему решил без вас, ясно было написано собирает только одну либо под мое устройство, и этот код указан с которым собирает.

Comment: Ну раз решили - опубликуйте ответ, помогите другим. В опубликованном куске кода я не вижу **никакого упоминания прогуарда** и как вы его применяете абсолютно не ясно, тогда как вы утверждаете что проблема именно с ним. APK может компилироваться под одну архитектуру тестового устройства когда вы запускаете установку на это устройство. Если вы запустите любой другой вариант сборки - должны быть скомпилированы все. Хотя в 3.2 может быть по-другому и кто знает что и как вы делаете...